# MongoDB push item only if it does not exist

Tags: mongodb, push, updating

I have a document with the following fields:

```
{
    "id" : 15,
    "existingCodes" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c49a6c03a95f50b15409296"),
            "code" : "first"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c49a6c03a95f50b15409295"),
            "code" : "second"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c49a6c03a95f50b15409294"),
            "code" : "third"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c49a6c03a95f50b15409293"),
            "code" : "fourth"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that I'm trying to push a new object to the `existingCodes` array but making sure that the `code` value does not already exist, and every solution that I've tried is not working.

I've tried to achieve this using `$push` and `$ne`, but it adds duplicate field:

```
db.getCollection('codes').update({ id: 15, 'existingCodes.code': { $ne: 'first' } }, { $push: { existingCodes: { code: 'first' } } })
```

But it doesn't add the duplicate field if I change `$ne` to match "second" or any other existing `code` value different than "first", and I don't understand why.

I've also tried to use `$addToSet`:

```
db.getCollection('codes').update({ id: 15, }, { $addToSet: { existingCodes: { code: 'first' } } })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to set works fine you are using **id** in the match condition in place of **_id**
attaching a screenshot as well!
[addToset.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eN8D.png)